# Extract substring from string using php

Tags: php, string, substring

I need to extract a substring from another string using php.

```
$string = 'This is my string that conteined a Code:XYZ123';
$code = substr($text, -1, strpos($string,'Code:'));
echo $code ; // return 3
```

I need the whole code for example XYZ123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code  :

```
$string = 'This is my string that conteined a Code:XYZ123';
$code = substr($string ,strpos($string,'Code:'));
echo $code;
```

Make sure this is helpful to you.

Comment: The output to this is `Code:XYZ123`

Comment: Yeah he wants the actual code. Not 'Code:' plus the code

Answer (score 3):

You need the starting position of "Code:" plus the length of "Code:"

```
$string = 'This is my string that conteined a Code:XYZ123'; 
$code = substr($string, strpos($string,'Code:') + 5); 
echo $code; //XYZ123
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to explode the string my `Code:` and echo the second part of the array

```
$code = explode( 'Code:', $string );
echo $code[ 1 ]
```